# OpenGL: Не передается информация из вершинного шейдера в фрагментный шейдер

Tags: opengl, шейдеры

Написал opengl программу, которая рисует треугольник. Но данные о цвете из вершинного шейдера почему-то не доходят до фрагментного (рисуется черный треугольник). Если задавать цвет в фрагментном шейдере все работает.

Вершинный шейдер:

```
# version 430

 layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

out vec4 color;

void main(){
gl_Position=vec4(position, 1.0);
color=vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
#version 430

in vec4 color;

out vec4 FragColor;


void main(){
 FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: пробовали добавить `layout (location=1) out vec4 color;` ?

Answer (score -2):

Все заработало. Я переписал программу без классов(в один файл) и все заработало.

Comment: Вот почему в вопросы нужно сразу добавлять [mcve].